# git - как вставить коммиты под ветку

Tags: git, smartgit

[image: Проблема]

Требуется сделать ребэйз так, чтобы параллельно перенести выделенные коммиты из develop в screen_fixes. Но не поверх, а под существующими! Чтобы выглядело так, как будто я начал свою ветку после develop.
Как такое провернуть? Использую SmartGit.

Comment: Команде `merge` не важно, кто раньше написал, кто позже. При слиянии нужно только подправлять конфликты вручную.

Comment: @AlexGlebe нужен не merge, а rebase.

Comment: Ну а `rebase` так и делает. В чём тогда вопрос? `git checkout screen_fixes` ; `git rebase develop`

Comment: rebase ставит коммиты ПОВЕРХ ветки! А мне надо ПОД ветку

Comment: Вот и подошли к главному. Я предлагаю `screen_fixes` поставить поверх `develop`. А вы почему-то отказываетесь.

Comment: «Чтобы выглядело так, как будто я начал свою ветку после develop.» — именно это и сделает rebase. Если у вас не так, приведите доказательства

Comment: https://a.radikal.ru/a39/2008/56/1c1b446f7e24.png - если я выберу этот пункт, то у меня эти 5 коммитов переместятся поверх screen_fixes (над коммитом "добавил лицензию"). А мне надо как-то их подсунуть снизу (под коммит "Splash Screen в соответствии...")

Comment: @SergeyMolchanovsky, ты говоришь какую-то ерунду.

Comment: Вы не выбрали нужную нить на фото.

Comment: Я понял, в чем дело. Нужно было применить rebase к самой ветке, а я тыкал на верхний коммит - он поверх коммита и ставил. Вот так: https://a.radikal.ru/a16/2008/46/dc1113d09a0c.png, не в Log Window, а в Branches Тогда коммиты переместятся под неё, как и нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Делаю через `git`. Как в **SmartGit** - не знаю.

`git checkout screen_fixes` - переходим в нить , что должна быть наверху. Самой свежей.
`git rebase origin/develop` - пересчитываю нить `screen_fixes` и ставлю поверх `develop`.
`git push --force origin master` - кидаю на сервер. Насильно, потому-что я теряю оригинальную ветку `master`.

Comment: Только push должен быть force, а в остальном вроде верно. Зачем удалил?

Comment: первые две команды возможно совместить - `git rebase develop screen_fixes`

Comment: А чего вдруг master-то? `git push --force origin screen_fixes`